# Update for Klarna (Woocommerce 3.0)

Tags: woocommerce, klarna

Since Woocommerce released Woocommerce 3.0, Klarnas pay plugin doesn't work.

For example i get this errors.

Notice: country was called incorrectly. Customer properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/twentyseventeen/page.php'), get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require('/themes/twentyseventeen/template-parts/page/content-page.php'), the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, do_shortcode, preg_replace_callback, do_shortcode_tag, WC_Shortcodes::checkout, WC_Shortcodes::shortcode_wrapper, WC_Shortcode_Checkout::output, WC_Shortcode_Checkout::checkout, wc_get_template, include('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php'), do_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_review'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, woocommerce_checkout_payment, WC_Payment_Gateways->get_available_payment_gateways, WC_Gateway_Klarna_Part_Payment->is_available, WC_Gateway_Klarna_Part_Payment->check_required_fields, WC_Gateway_Klarna_Helper->get_eid, WC_Legacy_Customer- in /mnt/persist/www/dev10/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4138

And

Notice: WC_Customer::get_country is deprecated since version 3.0! Use WC_Customer::get_billing_country instead. in /mnt/persist/www/dev10/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3830

Notice: WC_Customer::get_country is deprecated since version 3.0! Use WC_Customer::get_billing_country instead. in /mnt/persist/www/dev10/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3830

Notice: WC_Customer::get_country is deprecated since version 3.0! Use WC_Customer::get_billing_country instead. in /mnt/persist/www/dev10/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3830

Notice: WC_Customer::get_country is deprecated since version 3.0! Use WC_Customer::get_billing_country instead. in /mnt/persist/www/dev10/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3830

Notice: WC_Customer::get_country is deprecated since version 3.0! Use WC_Customer::get_billing_country instead. in /mnt/persist/www/dev10/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3830.

Are that anyone who have i solution to this yet?

Thanks!

Comment: you should instead ask the author of the plugin..

Comment: I have emailed the author (Krokedil) about this. You should too so they can get a move on.

Comment: Yeah, thats right! I have also emailed the author, hope that they will fix this soon!

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my comment, you should really ask Klarna to fix the errors in their plugin. However regarding your other problem, it is easily remedied. At least, it was for me.

Simply do a search for `get_country(` in your theme and plugin files. Replace all that you find with `get_billing_country(` instead. I had this referenced in my theme files. Upon changing it the error went away.

Comment: Okey, i will do this. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel If this solved your problem, please select the tickmark